# Persistent Navigation Bar Error in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, widget, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am new to flutter and wanted to add a persistent navigation bar that will contain 4 icons leading to 3 different pages with icon-1 as the default home screen. The code is attached below.

The version of the Persistent Bottom Nav Bar I am using is 4.0.2

**Home Screen**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myspace/widgets/right_drawer.dart';
import 'package:myspace/widgets/bottom_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent-tab-view.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text(
          'mySpace',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 24.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.blue.shade900
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          Builder(
            builder: (context) => IconButton(
                onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(),
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.blue.shade900, size: 30.0,)
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      endDrawer: const RightDrawerWidget(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomListWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

and the widget file for **Bottom Navigation Bar** :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myspace/Screens/homescreen.dart';
import 'package:myspace/Screens/chat_system.dart';
import 'package:myspace/Screens/help_and_support.dart';
import 'package:myspace/Screens/news.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent-tab-view.dart';

class BottomListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomListWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomListWidget> createState() => _BottomListWidgetState();
}

class _BottomListWidgetState extends State<BottomListWidget> {

  PersistentTabController _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PersistentTabView(
        context,
        controller: _controller,
        screens: _buildScreens(),
      items: _navBarItems(),
      confineInSafeArea: true,
      itemAnimationProperties: const ItemAnimationProperties(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        curve: Curves.ease,
      ),
      screenTransitionAnimation: const ScreenTransitionAnimation(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        curve: Curves.ease,
        animateTabTransition: true
      ),
      navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style10,
    );
  }
}

List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarItems() {
  return [
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
      title: ('Home'),
      activeColorPrimary: Colors.blue.shade800,
      inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
    ),
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.newspaper_sharp),
      title: ('Happenings'),
      activeColorPrimary: Colors.blue.shade800,
      inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
    ),
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.support_agent_rounded),
      title: ('Help'),
      activeColorPrimary: Colors.blue.shade800,
      inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
    ),
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.message),
      title: ('Chats'),
      activeColorPrimary: Colors.blue.shade800,
      inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
    ),
  ];
 }

 List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
  return [
    const HomeScreen(),
    const RecentNewsScreen(),
    const HelpAndSupport(),
    const ChatSystem()
  ];
 }
```

After building this app I am getting error as:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on EB2101 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/persistent-tab-view.widget.dart:368:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
      WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                     ^
/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/animations/animations.dart:55:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^
/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-6-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:44:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^
/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-8-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:44:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^
/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-11-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:46:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^
/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-12-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:46:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^
/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-13-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:46:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^
/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-14-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:46:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The package is 17 months old and doesn't support flutter version 3.0+ .. I assume that you are running flutter version >3 which isn't supported by this package.. Try some other package or downgrade flutter version. You can also fork the repo and update the widget binding codes and use them.

Comment: Can you name some of the other packages, I have tried using Bottom Navigation Bar, but not getting desired result

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2

Comment: When you build using these packages a new copy of all codes is saved in your project in cache. So you can use it. Unless you change the version in pubspec it won't be updated

Comment: I used this version and got the error as shown below.
```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Are tou using an older version of flutter?